# Echo output of linux dialog utlity in bash script

Tags: bash, output

I'm working on a simple bash script menu, and I've followed [this guide](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/A_menu_box) to get started.

It works fine, but I don't really like how stderr is redirected to a file and then used in the main loop.

In my script I have a few functions that draw different things. I'm trying to modify them to work without having to write to the files. One of the functions to draw a menu looks like th is (simplified):

```
function render_menu()
{
    dialog --clear --backtitle "$backtitle" --title "Some Title" --menu "My  fancy menu" 50 15 4 "one" "option 1" "two" "option 2"
    echo $?
}
```

And it is called from the main loop like:

```
while true; do
    selection="$(render_menu)" 

    case $selection in
            Quit) break;;
            Back) #some logic;;
            *) #some logic;;
    esac
done
```

But it doesn't work, when I run the script I don't see the menu. I assume because the output of `dialog` has been redirected?

The way I want it to work is that the dialog is displayed, and the output from it is stored in the variable `selection`. Is that possible without the need for an external file? If not, why so?

Comment: All the output of a command that is assigned to a variable is put inside that  variable. `Selection` will contain the return code and the entire contents of dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Try as:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

function render_menu()
{
  exec 3>&1
  selection=$(dialog --clear --backtitle "$backtitle" --title "Some Title" --menu "My  fancy menu" 50 15 4 "one" "option 1" "two" "option 2" 2>&1 1>&3)
  exit_code=$?
  exec 3>&-
}

render_menu 
echo $exit_code
echo $selection
```

*** Addendum 1 ***

If, for some reason, the function must be called as $(render_menu ...) and return result in stdout, this is another possibility:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#

function render_menu()
{
   selection=$(dialog --clear --backtitle "$backtitle" --title "Some Title" --menu "My  fancy menu" 50 15 4 "one" "option 1" "two" "option 2" 2>&1 1>&3)
  exit_code=$?
   echo $selection
}

exec 3>&1
selection="$(render_menu  2>&1 1>&3)"
exec 3>&-
echo $selection
```

Comment: That's not really how I would like it. I prefer to write my scripts so that the functions echo a value back, and then I just use command expansion to put it in a variable. Perhaps I should have been more clear in the question that I want to leave the loop as-is and modify the _render menu function only_

Comment: These are minor variants over same answer. Updated, feel free of provide your own variants.